# Sql Not placing Select option to database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have three options for a photo or video being uploaded to the site , i have this select option to pick what the file is being uploaded sorta like a tag. its not placing it in the database. here is my code:

Here is where i call on it

```
$type1 = $_POST['type'];
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($type);

          $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos 
SET photo='$newname', title='$title', date='$date', author='$by' , type='$type'")
```

Here is where it is made

```
<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="Pic">Picture</option>
  <option value="Video">Video</option>
  <option value="Gif">Animated picture (GIF)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You use $type on the second line, but you only have $type1 variable defined. A typo :)

Answer (score 3):

use this `INSERT` syntax

```
INSERT INTO photos (photo, title, date, author, type )
VALUES ('$newname', '$title', '$date','$by' , '$type')
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please read the article below how to prevent from it,

- [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is the real code? It looks like when you're escaping, you're not using the actual data from the Select.

```
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($type); // You are escaping the $type variable, which is NULL, it was just declared
```

But you're reading the data from the Select using this variable name

```
$type1 = $_POST['type'];
```

So you're using `$type1` somewhere, and `$type` somewhere else.